# Data calculations excluded within switch statement loop

Tags: java, while-loop, switch-statement, nested-loops

My final project for class is a text based game. So far I have it working how I want, except for 1 or 2 issues. First big issue is when I enter my "magic" menu (switch statement loop) none of the data has any impact. Meaning if the user's HP drops below 0, they don't die, it doesn't happen until you exit the loop. I've messed with it, and made it work, but it broke other parts of the code, so please help if you can.

Another solution I was able to do was setting the boolean value to false after each case, making the user enter a case, then it jumps out of the switch, which works great, except it executes the entire switch loop, meaning every single input.
Here's the main code, keep in mind it has another class

```
package textRPG;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LoopyLoop {

    private static int maxEnemyHealth = 155;
    private static int enemyAttackDmg = 25;
    private static int health = 109;
    private static int attackDmg = 30;
    private static int mana = 15;
    private static int numHealthPots = 3;
    private static int healthPotionHealAmount = 30;
    private static int healthPotionDropChance = 20;
    private static int manaPotionRecoveryAmount = 12;
    private static int count = 0;
    private static int count2 = 0;
    private static int expUp = 0;
    private static int level = 1;   

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpellsAndAbilities spells = new SpellsAndAbilities();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();
        //String Array for enemies, more can be added, or taken away
        String[] enemies = {"Skeleton", "Zombie", "Goblin", "Tiny Dragon", "Ben Afleck", "Little weird man", "Huge Bee", "Jeff", "Crazy Ray"};          
        //Set a variable running to true, to allow the program to run, so that if the user chooses to end the game early, they can do so
        boolean running = true;
        System.out.println("==================================================================");
        System.out.println("Welcome to Mysterical World of Mysterical Things!");
        System.out.println("Please press the number corresponding the action you wish to take.");   
        System.out.println("==================================================================");
        //Clause to keep the game running with invalid inputs
        GAME:           
        while(running) {

            int enemyHealth = rand.nextInt(maxEnemyHealth);
            String enemy = enemies[rand.nextInt(enemies.length)];
            System.out.println("\n\t### " + enemy + " has appeared! ###\n");

            while (enemyHealth > 0) {
                 System.out.println("\tYour HP: " + health);
                 System.out.println("\tYour Mana: " + mana);
                 System.out.println("\t" + enemy + "'s HP: " + enemyHealth);
                 System.out.println("\n\tWhat would you like to do?");
                 System.out.println("\t1. Attack");
                 System.out.println("\t2. Spells");
                 System.out.println("\t3. Use potion");
                 System.out.println("\t4. Run");
                 String input = in.nextLine();

                if (input.equals("1")) {
                    int damageDealt = rand.nextInt(attackDmg);
                    int damageTaken = rand.nextInt(enemyAttackDmg);
                    enemyHealth -= damageDealt;
                    health -= damageTaken;
                    System.out.println("\t>>> You hit the " + enemy + " for " + damageDealt + " damage <<<");
                    System.out.println("\t>>> The " + enemy + " hit you for " + damageTaken + " damage <<<");
                    System.out.println();
                    if(health < 1) {
                        System.out.println("\t=== You died! ===");
                        break;
                    }
                    //
                    //Problem Starts Here
                    //
                }else if (input.equals("2")) {
                    boolean set=true;
                    while(set) {                        
                        System.out.println("____________________________________________\n");
                        System.out.println("1. Fireblast (Cost: 6 mana, Damage: 10-19)");                   
                        System.out.println("2. Ice Sickle (Cost: 9 mana, Damage: 22-26)");                      
                        System.out.println("3. Whirlwind (Cost: 14 mana, Damage: 31-36)");                      
                        System.out.println("4. Earth shard (Cost: 28 mana, Damage: 38-42)");                        
                        System.out.println("5. Heal (Cost: 50 mana, Heals: 35 to 55 HP)");                      
                        System.out.println("6. Exit this menu");
                        System.out.println("____________________________________________");
                        int spellInput = in.nextInt();

                        switch (spellInput) {

                        case 1: if(mana >= 6) {
                            mana -= 6;
                            int damageDealt = spells.fireBlast();
                            int damageTaken = rand.nextInt(enemyAttackDmg);
                            enemyHealth -= damageDealt;
                            health -= damageTaken;                                                  
                            System.out.println("\t====================");
                            System.out.println("\tYou cast Fire Blast!");
                            System.out.println("\t====================");
                            System.out.println("\n\t>>> Fireblast hits the " + enemy + " for " + damageDealt + " damage <<<"); 
                            System.out.println("\t>>> You took " + damageTaken+ " damage<<<"); 
                            System.out.println();                   
                            break;
                            }
                            else {
                            break;
                            }                                                       

                        case 2: if (mana >= 9) {
                            mana -= 9;
                            int damageDealt = spells.iceSickle();
                            int damageTaken = rand.nextInt(enemyAttackDmg);
                            enemyHealth -= damageDealt;
                            health -= damageTaken;                              
                            System.out.println("\t====================");
                            System.out.println("\tYou cast Ice Sickle!");
                            System.out.println("\t====================");
                            System.out.println("\n\t>>> Ice Sickle slashes the " + enemy + " for " + damageDealt + " damage <<<"); 
                            System.out.println("\t>>> You took " + damageTaken+ " <<<"); 
                            System.out.println();
                            break;
                        }
                        else {
                            System.out.println("You need more mana");
                            break;                                       
                        }   

                        case 3: if(mana >= 14) {
                            mana -= 14;     
                            int damageDealt = spells.whirlWind();
                            int damageTaken = rand.nextInt(enemyAttackDmg);
                            enemyHealth -= damageDealt;
                            health -= damageTaken;                      
                            System.out.println("\t====================");
                            System.out.println("\tYou cast Whirlwind!");
                            System.out.println("\t====================");
                            System.out.println("\n\t>>> Whirlwind ravages " + enemy + " for " + damageDealt + " damage <<<"); 
                            System.out.println("\t>>> You took " + damageTaken+ " <<<"); 
                            System.out.println();
                            break;
                        }
                        else {
                            break;
                        }


                        case 4: if(mana >= 28) {
                            mana -= 28; 
                            int damageDealt = spells.earthShard();
                            int damageTaken = rand.nextInt(enemyAttackDmg);
                            enemyHealth -= damageDealt;
                            health -= damageTaken;                      
                            System.out.println("\t====================");
                            System.out.println("\tYou cast Earth Shard!");
                            System.out.println("\t====================");
                            System.out.println("\n\t>>> Earth shard pummels " + enemy + " for " + damageDealt + " damage <<<"); 
                            System.out.println("\t>>> You took " + damageTaken+ " <<<"); 
                            System.out.println();
                            break;
                        }
                        else {
                            break;
                        }


                        case 5: if(mana >= 50) {
                            mana -= 50;                             
                            health += spells.Heal();
                            int damageTaken = rand.nextInt(enemyAttackDmg);                                 
                            health -= damageTaken;              
                            System.out.println("\t===============");
                            System.out.println("\tYou cast Heal!");
                            System.out.println("\t===============");
                            System.out.println("\n\t>>> You recover " + spells.Heal() + " HP <<<"); 
                            System.out.println("\t>>> You took " + damageTaken+ " damage <<<");
                            System.out.println("\tYour HP: " + health);
                            System.out.println("\tYour Mana: " + mana);
                            System.out.println();
                            break;
                        }
                        else {
                            break;;
                        }


                        case 6: set = false;

                        default: break;                 
                        }
                    }
                }

                else if (input.equals("3")) {   

                        if (numHealthPots > 0) {
                            count2++;
                            health += healthPotionHealAmount;
                            mana += manaPotionRecoveryAmount;
                            numHealthPots--;
                            System.out.println("\tYou drink a potion, healing for " + healthPotionHealAmount + " HP and recovering " + manaPotionRecoveryAmount + " mana" +
                                               "\n\t>> You now have " + health + " HP and " + mana +" Mana <<" +
                                               "\n\t>> You have " + numHealthPots + " potions left <<");
                        }

                        else {
                            System.out.println("\tYou have no potions left! Defeat enemies for a chance to get one!");
                        }

                } else if (input.equals("4")) {             
                            System.out.println("\tYou run away from the " + enemy + "!");
                    continue GAME;
                  }

                  else {                        
                        System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
                  }
            }

            if(health < 1) {
                System.out.println("You pitifully limp out of the dungeon, too weak to go on!");
                break;
            }
                count++;
                System.out.println("=========================================");
                System.out.println(" *** " + enemy +" was defeated! ***");
                System.out.println("### You have " + health + " HP ### \n### And " + mana + " mana ###");
                expUp += expUp + 25;            

            if (rand.nextInt(100) < healthPotionDropChance) {

                numHealthPots++;
                System.out.println(" # The " + enemy + " dropped a health potion");
                System.out.println(" # You now have " + numHealthPots + " health potion(s) # ");
            } 
                if(expUp > 99) {
                    level++;
                    health = health+22;
                    attackDmg = attackDmg + 2;
                    mana = mana + 7;
                    System.out.println("****** LEVEL UP!!! ******");
                    System.out.println("You are now level " + level + "!");
                    System.out.println("Each level up rewards 22 to total health, +2 to attack, and +7 to mana!");
                }
                System.out.println("=========================================");
                System.out.println("What would you like to do now?");
                System.out.println("Press 1 to continue fighting");
                System.out.println("Pess 2 to exit");

            String input = in.nextLine();

            while (!input.equals("1") && !input.equals("2")) {
                System.out.println("Invalid command");
                input = in.nextLine();
            }
            if (input.equals("1")) {
                System.out.println("You choose to continue, good luck!");
            }
            else if (input.equals("2")) {
                System.out.println("You exit the game");
                break;
            }
        }
                System.out.println("####################");
                System.out.println("Thanks for playing!");
                System.out.println("####################");
                System.out.println("Press 5 to see your score!");
                String input2 = in.nextLine();
                if (input2.equals("5")){
                    System.out.println("You defeated " + count + " enemies");
                    System.out.println("Max level achieved: " + level);
                    System.out.println("And you used " + count2 + " potions");                  
                }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Invalid input");
                        input2 = in.nextLine();
                    }
                in.close();
        }
}
```

Output ends up looking like this:

```
6. Exit this menu
____________________________________________
6
=========================================
 *** Tiny Dragon was defeated! ***
### You have 136 HP ### 
### And 6 mana ###
****** LEVEL UP!!! ******
```

Comment: case 1 and 2 don't have break statements in the else clause, if you don't end the case with `break;` the case below the current case will be executed as well, if that case doesn't have a break statement either then the case under that will be executed as well and so on

Comment: I cannot recommend strongly enough that you refactor your code into discrete methods.

Comment: I'm sorry for the mess, it's really bad, and there is no excuse. I should've wrote methods to execute all this, so I do sincerely apologize for asking for help with this mess,